# Try-Catch Block not reachable? Does having an inner try-finally block cause the outer try-catch block to be unreachable?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to code a simple website API call in Kotlin, but I am having some trouble implementing a try-catch block. It goes smoothly up until the final catch statement which turns the whole block into unreachable code.

```
     // REST web service call to get data from coinmarketcap API
inner class RetrieveFeedTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): String? {
 //            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        try {
            // create a connection
            val siteURL  = URL("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=200")
            val urlConn = siteURL.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConn.connect()
            // if there the connection is successful
            try {
                // reads the urlConn as a string
                val bufferedReader = urlConn.inputStream.bufferedReader()
                val stringBuilder = StringBuilder("")
                // each line from the json object
                var line : String?
                do {
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine()
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n")
                    if (line === null)
                        break
                } while (true)
                bufferedReader.close()
                return stringBuilder.toString()
            } catch (e : Exception) {
                throw e
            } finally {
                urlConn.disconnect()
            }
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            Log.e("NETWORK","Couldn't connect to the website: " + e)
            return null
        }
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        if (result == null) {
            // should return an error message
            testTextView!!.text = "Error with website"
        } else {
            testTextView!!.text = result
        }
    }

}
```

I thought that the final catch statement would allow the try block to be reached even if it does not connect? I was reading around and saw that the finally statement will always run so I thought that might be the problem, but when I converted that into a catch block, it still would give me the same unreachable code. I was wondering if this was just specific to Kotlin as I am just starting to learn it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The only compiler errors or warnings I get are lack of a return statement and not initializing `stringBuilder`.

Comment: Do TODO comments in Kotlin cause unreachable code blocks below it? When I commented that out, It fixed the problem, and I know see the other errors.

Comment: You can navigate to the definition of [`TODO`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html) and see that it returns `Nothing` and always throws.

Comment: Please don't put _SOLVED_ in the title or question but accept the answer that solved your question

Comment: @msrd0 I solved it myself so should I just remove the SOLVED?

Comment: No, you should write an answer to your own question, describing how you solved it, and mark that answer as accepted - then remove the _SOLVED_

Comment: Please make your question valid too. There isn't any `TODO()` in your code. Otherwise, no one can give you a concrete answer by only looking at the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a Kotlin thing for "TODO" statement to invalidate and make the code underneath unreachable? It seems I had to comment out the TODO comment above the try block to make it reachable.

Comment: Yes, since `TODO` always throws an exception and the compiler knows about it

Answer (score 1):

`TODO` will be the last executed line:

```
fun x() {
    TODO("Not implemented")
    //following is not reachable
    try {

    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
}
```

That's because of `TODO`s implementation:

```
public inline fun TODO(reason: String): Nothing = 
    throw NotImplementedError("An operation is not implemented: $reason")
```

It throws an exception and therefore returns `Nothing`, thus will always be the last thing executed (if reached).

Answer (score 0):

The lack of a `catch` clause in the inner `try` means that any exception there will be completely ignored. If you'd like to catch your exceptions in the outer `try` (while still including the inner `finally`) you can re-throw the inner exception by adding this to the inner `try`.

```
catch (e: Exception) {
    throw e
}
```